# Elasticsearch Parent and child

Tags: elasticsearch

If I put this:

```js
PUT /hostpid
{
  "mappings": {
    "parent": {},
    "child": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "parent" 
      }
    },"child1": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "parent" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

parent has two child , `child` and `child1`

I have a question, 
Have any way direct add new child2 in parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using the [put mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html)?

To test it I used your mappings:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "parent": {},
      "child": {
         "_parent": {
            "type": "parent"
         }
      },
      "child1": {
         "_parent": {
            "type": "parent"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then created another mapping like this:

```
PUT /test_index/child2/_mapping
{
   "child2": {
      "_parent": {
         "type": "parent"
      }
   }
}
```

And if I request the full mapping they all show up:

```
GET /test_index/_mapping
...
{
   "test_index": {
      "mappings": {
         "child2": {
            "_parent": {
               "type": "parent"
            },
            "_routing": {
               "required": true
            },
            "properties": {}
         },
         "parent": {
            "properties": {}
         },
         "child1": {
            "_parent": {
               "type": "parent"
            },
            "_routing": {
               "required": true
            },
            "properties": {}
         },
         "child": {
            "_parent": {
               "type": "parent"
            },
            "_routing": {
               "required": true
            },
            "properties": {}
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the code I used for testing:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/11846b82cbd0f818c4d1c187ebf905d41835b3b0

Comment: Really really Thanks you a lot !!